# Enabling c++11 in Eclipse CDT Neon with MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I've tried every setting that I've seen recommended here and it just spits out a whole bunch of [errors](https://puu.sh/qIh4q/aaadc2bbdb.png) at me.

Here are all the settings I've changed:

http://puu.sh/qIhLM/683798d8c8.png

Comment: Post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please. Links aren't helpful for diagnosis and future research.

Comment: The "minimal" amount of code I need to replicate this is literally none. I can have a blank program and it still throws these errors.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your installation probably, we can't tell from what you posted though.